# Open-Closed Principle and Builder pattern

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles

Can anyone share sample of using Builder pattern to confirm OCP (Open-Closed Principle).
Which else patterns are linked with OCP?

Comment: OCP == Open-Closed principle?

Comment: **What's wrong with this question? OCP(Open-Closed principle)**

Comment: You should elaborate a little more: The context and the efforts you're doing to answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just came from reading [The Open Closed Principle from Jeremy Miller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546578.aspx#id0390046), and it's a great explanation of OCP and other related SOLID principles. It doesn't mention the Builder Pattern but it recommended this patterns for OCP implementation:

- [Chain of Responsability pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)
- [Double dispatch pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)